# Notepad++ stopped working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, wine, notepad-plus-plus

I stumbled upon an issue with Notepad++ today on Ubuntu 22.04, where it just didn't load. Clicking on the desktop icon doesn't do anything.

Running it from the terminal gave the following:

```
$ notepad-plus-plus   
Installing application..   
Running hook '/snap/notepad-plus-plus/363/sommelier/hooks/pre-install'   
Starting application..   
wine: cannot find L"/home/<UserName>/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine/dosdevices
/z:/home/<UserName>/snap/notepad-plus-plus/363/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus.exe"
```

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question. However put your Answer in a seperate 'Answer' rather than within the question.

Comment: Hi @andrew.46. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

I used the solution suggested by Siao-Han (Notepad++ has stopped working) with a small change since the answer was intended for Linux Mint and not for Ubuntu.
The only difference is swapping the rm -rf * from Linux Mint for the Ubuntu command rm -r * to remove all files.
The following is the adapted answer for Ubuntu:

```
cd "/home//snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine/dosdevices /z:/home//snap/notepad-plus-plus/363/notepad-plus-plus/"
rm -r *
wget https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus plus/releases/download/v8.4/npp.8.4.portable.x64.zip
unzip npp.8.4.portable.x64.zip
mv notepad++.exe notepad-plus-plus.exe
```

And like @Siao-Han said, "Afterwards running notepad-plus-plus would work :)"
Thanks to Siao-Han for the solution.

Comment: Though is is not an answer to your question, but you may give a try to Sublime Text, it is similar to Notepad++ and has native linux builds.